# getting lots of spam from "unknown" and helo localhost

Tags: email, spam, whm, email-spam, exim

On our server, we keep receiving spam with the following headers. We are using whm 11.44 and exim.

Return path is always:
Return-path: <>

and it says Received: from unknown (HELO localhost)

Both which raise flags. We're just not sure exactly how to stop/reject them.

```
From - Mon Feb 16 14:27:02 2015
X-Account-Key: account3
X-UIDL: UID10475-1296887657
X-Mozilla-Status: 0001
X-Mozilla-Status2: 00000000
X-Mozilla-Keys:                                                                                 
Return-path: <>
Envelope-to: me@myserver.com
Delivery-date: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 09:13:38 -0600
Received: from [122.160.73.62] (port=10732 helo=122.160.73.62)
by myserver.myserver.com with smtp (Exim 4.82)
id 1YNN0Z-00056c-7P
for me@myserver.com; Mon, 16 Feb 2015 08:50:47 -0600
Received: from unknown (HELO localhost) (intlimd@highgrove.net@214.92.72.48)
by 122.160.73.62 with ESMTPA; Mon, 16 Feb 2015 20:23:11 +0530
From: intlimd@highgrove.net
To: myemail@myserver.com
Subject: Do not disapoint your girl this night

http://mandatory.natur.com/ Real magic in your life
```

Comment: This would probably get a better response on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Your call cannot be completed as dialed. Please check the area code and dial again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the full logs of your this mail with the following command and let me know so that we can assist you.

```
cat  /var/log/exim_mainlog | grep 1YNN0Z-00056c-7P
```